# iframe内のフォームの送信で、親フレームを遷移・リロードさせたい

Tags: php, html, cakephp

インラインフレーム内部のページでPOSTした場合、親ページを全体をリロードする方法がわかりません。

開発環境
PHP  5.2.8
CakePHP 2.6.2
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上図はメインページ/×××/mainの中にiframeで/×××/sampleが表示されいる例になります。
①のnameのテキストボックスに名前をセットしてOKを押すとDBに更新されますが
iframe内のページのみが遷移してメインページがリロードをされません。
これをiframe内のページ/×××/sampleでPOSTした結果
ページ全体が/×××/mainに遷移するか、更新後全体をリロードする方法がないでしょうか
よろしくお願いします。
下記がコードの抜粋になります。

main.ctp

```
------------------------------------------------------
<?php echo $this->Form->create('×××'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('id',array('type' => 'hidden')); ?>
<iframe src="/×××/sample" height="300" ></iframe>
*iframe内で更新したnameが表示されます
------------------------------------------------------
```

sample.ctp

```
------------------------------------------------------
<?php echo $this->Form->create('×××'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('id',array('type' => 'hidden')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('name',array('size' =>'15','label'=>false)); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->submit('  OK  ',array('div'=>false)); ?>
------------------------------------------------------
```

sample.php

```
------------------------------------------------------
if($this->×××->save($this->data)) {
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'main'));
}else{
    $this->redirect(array('action' => 'logout'));
}
------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

下記のようにformにtargetを指定して対応しました。

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('×××',array('target' => '_top')); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

cakephp側では解決できないと思うのでフロント側(Javascript等)でiframe内のイベントを拾って親ページもリロードするという形にすればいいんんじゃないでしょうか。
参考にJqueryでのiframeイベントの検知方法とかのURLを貼っておきます。
http://zxcvbnmnbvcxz.com/jquery-iframe-loaded/

Comment: いろいろ試しましたがうまくいかず、
結局
<?php echo $this->Form->create('×××',array('target' => '_top')); ?>
のようにtargetを指定しました。
参考になりました。ありがとうございました。